# loading video files in an array (processing)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, processing, video-processing

i load some video files in an array and play the files. later i stop all the files with the array.

it works but i get an error message from processing: seek operation failed

is my code correct?
(here i dont post the whole code only the array and video parts)

```
//array
Movie[] filme = new Movie[17];

void setup() {
//load files in array
  for(int i=0; i<filme.length; i++) {
     filme[i] = new Movie(this, i+".m2v");
  }

}

void draw() {
  //example play video
  filme[15].play(); //spielt das video ab
  image(filme[15],0,0); //zeigt das video an

  //later if something happened i stop the videos
  if (something happened) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filme.length; i++) {
          filme[i].stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is responsible for this error? What is the error message?

Comment: What is `Movie`, `play`, `stop` etc...?

Comment: @nullpointer They are part of Processing's Video library. Please notice the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: @fab Can you please post a [mcve], including links to the video files? Note that you don't need to post all 17 of them if you can get the error to happen with just one file.

Comment: @fab can you test with h264 encoded files instead .m2v files (not sure how well these are supported) ?